# Python Tornado server stops when autoreload is applied

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I try to set Python's Tornado server autoreload as stated here: https://gist.github.com/renaud/10356841

My part of code with autoreload settings is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    
    tornado.autoreload.start()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(project_path()):
        [tornado.autoreload.watch(f'{root}/{file}') for f in files if f.endswith('.py')]
    
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The application starts but when any changes are done the server stops as if I press Stop in IDE:

> Process finished with exit code 0

The project works fine without autoreload. This behaviour is because of autoreload. Also I checked all files' paths that I add to watch, the paths are valid.

In other details my code is seemingly the same as from the link above.

Why the server stops where any changes are done?

Comment: Probably the issue is described here: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2243
Autoreload fails in Pycharm. It works when I start server without IDE